# mockk fails with function returning List

Tags: java, kotlin, mockk

I have a function in Class Student.

```
class Student {
var name: String? = null
var marks: String? = null

fun getMarks():List<String>{
    return listOf<String>("10","10","10")
}
}
```

I have mocked this class Student and now want to return list of data.

This below test fail with error error

```
 @Test
    fun test1(){
       val student =  mockk<Student>()
        every { student.getMarks() }.returns(listOf("9","5"))
        student.getMarks()
    }
}
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Superclass java.util.List of java.util.List_1_Proxy is an interface (declaration of 'java.util.List_1_Proxy' appears in /data/user/0/com.myapp.mytestapp/app_dxmaker_cache/Generated_-597883428.jar)
```

Comment: why do you want to mock a list? why not use the real thing with mock elements?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I can mock a MutableList successfully. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @lance-java while I agree that it's very unusual to mock a list, sometimes you want to do something like `every { mockList[any()] } returns "x"` and you just can't do that with a real list as you would have to populate an infinite number of elements.

Comment: I have updated my code above with an example.

Comment: I've written countless tests in my lifetime and never had to mock a list

Comment: Please read the full description. I have edited my query. My motive is not to mock the list, but to mock a function returning the list. This fails. Kindly let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: @lance-java the OP is not really mocking a list, they're mocking a method that happens to return a list. I.e., what is mocked is `Student`, not `List` itself

Comment: In Kotlin, it's idiomatic to use properties instead of getters. So instead of `getMarks()` you would simply use the `marks` property. You've already created a `marks` property, maybe what you want is to [define a getter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters) for it.

Comment: +1 to what @k314159 said. On top of that, the `marks` property and the `getMarks()` method have different return types. It might just be a mistake in the sample code you shared, or you might have the same inconsistency in your real code – better to avoid that as it can create confusion

Comment: @user2340612 the OP changed the question, initially they were trying to mock a list

Comment: Full agreement that it is never, not even once, appropriate to mock a list.  If you want a zillion `"x"` elements, use `Collections.nCopies(n, "x")`, which doesn't actually materialize n elements.

Comment: @LouisWasserman what if you want `every { mockList[any()] } answers { Random.nextInt() }`?

Comment: I _don't_, and wouldn't.  Randomness in a test?  No.  That's to say nothing about how such a mock would break on iteration, and tests shouldn't be sensitive to how the list is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

If I try running the test with the exact same code you posted, I get a different error:

```
io.mockk.MockKException: Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
```

I believe the error message is a bit misleading, and I think the underlying issue is that the generated bytecode effectively contains 2 methods with the same name but different return types:

- `public final String getMarks() { return this.marks; }` – generated from the `var marks: String? = null` property
- `public final List getMarks() { return CollectionsKt.listOf(new String[]{"10", "10", "10"}); }` generated from your `fun getMarks`

If you rename the method for example, I can run it with no issues:

```kotlin
@Test
fun test1() {
    val student = mockk<Student>()
    every { student.getSomeMarks() } returns listOf("9", "5")
    println(student.getSomeMarks())
    Assert.assertEquals(listOf("9", "5"), student.getSomeMarks())
}
```

which prints `[9, 5]` and passes successfully.

I think you should strongly consider either renaming the property or the method to disambiguate them, or declaring it as a [computed property/override the getter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#getters-and-setters).

Having said that, there might not even be a need to mock the function. Depending on what you want to test, it might be better to use a real object instead of a mock – hard to tell without knowing what the real code is and what you're trying to achieve, though.